# Why the two methods give different answers?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, approximation, ratio

**Question**

If Kinetic energy of the body is increased by $300\text{%}$, its momentum will increase by:

**Method 1**:Using proportionality

$$Ke=\frac{P^2}{2m}$$where Ke is Kinetic energy and P is momentum

Since mass is constant,
$$\frac{Ke_i}{Ke_f}=\frac{P_i^2}{P_f^2}$$
$$\frac{Ke_i}{4Ke_i}=\frac{P_i^2}{P_f^2}$$
$$P_f=2P_i$$
$$∆P=2P_i-P_i=P_i$$
**Change in momentum is 100%**

**METHOD 2**:Using differentiation

$$Ke=\frac{P^2}{2m}$$
Differentiating both sides
$$dKe=\frac{2Pdp}{2m}$$
Approximating $$dKe=∆Ke$$
$$∆Ke=3Ke$$
$$3Ke=\frac{2Pdp}{2m}$$
$$\frac{3Ke*2m}{2P}=dP$$
$$Ke*2m=P^2$$
Substituting ,
$$\frac{3*P^2}{2P}=dP$$
$$(dP/P)*100=\frac32*100=150%$$
**Change in momentum =150%**

Why the two methods give different answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, $dKe$ is infinitesimal small change in kinetic energy i.e. $dKe\to 0$ while $\Delta Ke$ is change in kinetic energy much much larger than $0$ i.e. $\Delta Ke>>0$ (in this case). Thus
$$dKe<<\Delta Ke$$
Therefore using $dKe=\Delta Ke$ gives a large difference in the results due to overestimation.

The first method computes $\text{%}\Delta P$ correctly by taking actual difference $\Delta Ke$ (without any approximation) while second method computes $\text{%}\Delta P$ incorrectly due to overestimation by taking $dKe=\Delta Ke$

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct. As for the second one, you can't say $dKe=\Delta Ke$, because in this case $\Delta Ke $is very large.Had it been a very small increase in Kinetic energy (say, $0.1\%$), this substitution ($dKe=\Delta Ke$) would have given the correct answer. However, even in that case, only the first method gives the exact answer, while the second one is just an approximation,to make calculations easier.